# hidden-sm in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a simple sidebar which will be hidden on small devices..

But can't make it work.. `#sidebar` is either hidden or the `padding-left` on `#main` is set to `0`

```
<div id="sidebar" class="hidden-sm">sidebar</div>
<div id="main">test</div>

@media (max-width:767px) {
    #main {
        padding-left:0;
    }
}

#sidebar {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    background:red;
}

#main {
    padding-left:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided I'm interpreting what you're trying to say correctly, when the sidebar is hidden, you want the main div to go to the left most edge of the screen?

Simply getting rid of the padding styling for that div made that happen.

**[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/bLHycPAlDu)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="sidebar" class="hidden-sm">sidebar</div>
<div id="main">test</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, you can use the Bootstrap class `pull-left` instead of `float: left;` in the CSS for your sidebar item.

Comment: What if I want the sidebar to have height 100% of the viewport?

Comment: Setting the height to 100% won't work because you've set the width using pixels. You'll have to use a bit of JS/JQ to get the height of the viewport, then set the height of the sidebar based on that.